# Problema al usar variable creada en una funcion en otras funciones usando global

Tags: php

Tengo el código que muestro a continuación, quiero usar la variable `$arrPiezas` fuera de esa función pero tras usar `global` sigue sin dejarme y me muestra este error:

> Undefined variable: arrPiezas

Básicamente que no esta encontrando la variable, pero no sé porque ya que creo que usando `global` debería funcionar, alguna sugerencia?

Me pide que añada más detalles pero la verdad creo que se entiende perfectamente la pregunta, de lo contrario podeis sugerir cualquier cambio para que se entienda mejor y lo solucionare, muchas gracias a todos!!

```
<?php

$array = [4, 4,
    2, 5, 4, 0,
    2, 1, 4, 2,
    0, 1, 1, 0,
    4, 4, 0, 3,
    0, 0, 4, 3,
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 4, 0, 0,
    4, 4, 3, 5,
    5, 5, 2, 4,
    1, 1, 0, 5,
    4, 1, 0, 4,
    1, 0, 2, 4,
    3, 5, 1, 2,
    1, 4, 2, 0,
    0, 1, 5, 2,
    1, 5, 0, 4];


function tamanioYpiezas($arrayPiezas){
    global $alto, $ancho, $arrPiezas;

    $length = count($arrayPiezas);
    $alto = $arrayPiezas[0];
    $ancho = $arrayPiezas[1];
    
    $arrPiezas = array_slice($arrayPiezas, 2);

    for($i = 1; $i < ($length/$alto); $i++){
        
        global ${"pieza".$i};
        ${"pieza".$i} = [];
        
            for($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++){

                array_push(${"pieza".$i}, $arrPiezas[0]);
                array_shift($arrPiezas);

            }
    }
    //print_r($pieza1); print_r($pieza2); print_r($pieza3); print_r($pieza4); print_r($pieza16);
}


function tablero ($cantidadPiezas){

    echo $cantidadPiezas;

}

tablero($arrPiezas);
tamanioYpiezas($array);

?>
```

Comment: debe ser porque la variable no se llama "arrPiezas" la que declaraste como global se llama "array"

Comment: Como indica Leo en su respuesta, no está muy claro en tu código qué variable quieres que sea global exactamente. Si te fijas en el ejemplo 1 que aparece en la documentación, las variables globales se declaran e inicializan antes de las funciones https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php Las tres que tú intentas usar como globales NO se han definido así y no parecen estar usándose fuera del método `tamanioYpiezas`

Comment: no se donde has visto un global $array, puede ser que yo no lo este viendo pero creo que ese no es el problema, yo declaro como global $alto, $ancho, $arrPiezas;

Comment: a $arrPiezas la estoy llamando en la function tablero($cantidadPiezas) a la cual al llamarla la paso $arrPiezas, probare ha declararla fuera de la function

Comment: @DanielMorales Fíjate en el ejemplo que te he enlazado antes. Leo lo está viendo como global porque lo que se declara e instancia al principio, antes de definir las funciones es lo que suele interpretarse como global luego dentro de ellas.

Comment: me parece que estas mal interpretando la función global, con global especificas las variables que no se encuentran en el mismo scope de la función, entonces al decirle global $arrPiezas, le estas diciendo que esa variable ya ha sido definida en algún otro lugar fuera de tu función. Por lo que vi a la variable "$arrPiezas" no la has declarado anteriormente lo que si está declarado es la variable "$array" que está fuera la función y es valido usar global.

Comment: @LeoOdriozola he definido las variables globales fuera de la function y ahora no me muestra ningun error pero tampoco me muestar nada, es como que no recoge los datos que se deberian haber introducido al llamar a $arrPiezas en la primera function por lo que al llamarle en la segunda function sigue vacia, porque?

Comment: tambien preguntar como puedo definir entonces la variable dinamica de ${"pieza".$i} fuera de la function y seguir haciendo que sea global, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya te lo dijeron antes, declara la variable fuera de la función, y ya entonces dentro la llamas con Global.
En PHP las variables que se declaran dentro de las funciones son locales y no pueden ser accedidas a ellas desde fuera de la función, y las variables que se declaran fuera son globales y no pueden ser accedidas desde DENTRO de la función.
Ahí es donde se usa `global`, para decirle a PHP que nos estamos refiriendo a la variable global, no es tanto para declarar una variable como global.
Aunque bueno, en este caso simplemente con que inicialices `$arrPiezas` como un array, te debería funcionar.

y respondiendo a tu pregunta de por qué no muestra nada, lo que hiciste con el `array_shift($arrPiezas);` fue quitarle todos los elementos al array, y ese Array es el que estás intentando mostrar con `tablero($arrPiezas);`

y otro detalle, `echo` no funciona para arrays, solo para strings. debes usar `print_r();`

Ahora bien, realmente no se entiende que quieres hacer con ese codigo. ¿Quieres mostrar todos los arrays de piezas que hiciste?
¿Quieres mostrar el array vacío?

Mira, hice lo que creo que es lo que buscabas hacer. no usé variables dinámicas, en su lugar usé una matriz para guardar los datos. Espero que te sirva!

```
 <?php

    $array = [4, 4,
        2, 5, 4, 0,
        2, 1, 4, 2,
        0, 1, 1, 0,
        4, 4, 0, 3,
        0, 0, 4, 3,
        0, 0, 1, 1,
        1, 4, 0, 0,
        4, 4, 3, 5,
        5, 5, 2, 4,
        1, 1, 0, 5,
        4, 1, 0, 4,
        1, 0, 2, 4,
        3, 5, 1, 2,
        1, 4, 2, 0,
        0, 1, 5, 2,
        1, 5, 0, 4];
    

    $matriz = array(array());


    function tamanioYpiezas($arrayPiezas){

        $length = count($arrayPiezas);
        $alto = $arrayPiezas[0];
        $ancho = $arrayPiezas[1];
        global $matriz;
        
        $arrPiezas = array_slice($arrayPiezas, 2);

        for($i = 1; $i < ($length/$alto); $i++){
            
                for($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++){

                    $matriz[$i-1][$j] = $arrPiezas[0];
                    array_shift($arrPiezas);

                }
        }

    }
   

    function tablero ($cantidadPiezas){

        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($cantidadPiezas) ; $i++) { 
            echo "Array de piezas: ";
            
            print_r($cantidadPiezas[$i][0]);
            print_r($cantidadPiezas[$i][1]);
            print_r($cantidadPiezas[$i][2]);
            print_r($cantidadPiezas[$i][3]);
            echo "<br>";
        
        }

    }

    tamanioYpiezas($array);
    tablero($matriz);
    

    ?>
```

Comment: porque solo usas global en la $matriz? y no en arrPiezas, ancho y alto?

Comment: o porque estas declarando las variables fuera de la funcion si relamente no estas usandose para nada, es para poder llamarlas como global mas adelante en caso de que las necesitases?

Comment: Uso `global` en la matriz para hacer referencia a que voy a usar la variable que esta declarada fuera de la función. Y respecto a por qué declaraba las otras variables fuera de la función... tienes razón no hacía falta. Ya modifiqué el código :D